# Convert/Migrate all repository versions from github to mercurial

Tags: github, migration, mercurial, repository, version

I have been using github for my code until now but I have to switch to Mercurial and delete my github repository.

How can I or is it even possible to **migrate all github repository versions to Mercurial repository**? I would like to keep all versions of the code.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't have enough experience doing this to feel I should leave an answer; but the basic direction I would take is to use the hg-git extension to pull from github into local HG repositories. Details to work out would be what the branch structure should be, etc.  There are plenty of examples here about similar topics: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hg-git plus of course http://hg-git.github.io/ or https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HgGit

Answer (score 0):

Mercurial provides an extension "Convert" which can convert repositories from other SCMs to Mercurial.

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension

Add the following lines to your .hgrc to enable the extension :

```
[extensions]
hgext.convert=
```

Then following command can be used to convert repository (Git, in your case) to Mercurial:

```
hg convert SOURCE [DEST]
```